What is the effect of temperature on the reaction of a halohydrin with a base (NaH)?
If you take trans bromohydrin for example, the addition of base for either SN2 substitution to form an epoxide or elimination (deprotonation of a beta-Hydrogen) to form a cyclohexanone would result in the same number of net products. The main reasoning I see for why heat favors elimination is that more products are made, but how does temperature affect this reaction when the product count is same for substitution and elimination?

Which is the most acidic proton in the molecule?

The H from the OH, but what would that have to do with this question?

The rate constant is proportional to $e^{-\frac{\Delta G^{\ddagger}}{RT}}$. The effect of temperature changes depending on the size of the barrier.

@Emilia   So the OH will be deprotonated setting up the epoxide formation. There will be no deprotonation of the much less acidic beta-Hydrogen. Heating speeds up the epoxide formation

I think what you are looking for is how the position of equilibrium changes with increasing temperature, provided that number of products is the same for substitution and elimination (per mole of reactants).
Background
The position of equilibrium (for each mechanism) is dependent on the $\Delta G$ of the reactions. The more negative $\Delta G$ is, the more spontaneous the reaction.
Given that the number of products for elimination is more than that of substitution, $\Delta S_{elim}$ is more positive than $\Delta S_{sub}$ due to more products produced (given that products are in the same phase). Hence, with increasing temperature, $\Delta G_{elim} (= \Delta H - T\Delta S)$ becomes more negative compared to $\Delta G_{sub}$, so elimination becomes more spontaneous than substitution, which is why elimination product is favoured, as you mentioned.
To answer your question,
Typically, we consider $\Delta H$ and $\Delta S$ to be approximately independent of temperature. While the number of products is not the only determinant of $\Delta S$ , the same number of products will result in similar $\Delta S$ . Hence, as temperature increases, the rate of change of $\Delta G$ is $-\Delta S$, which is approximately equal for both reactions (you can imagine the graph of $\Delta G$  against T having a gradient of $-\Delta S$ . For all $T$, the difference in $\Delta G$ is the difference in $\Delta H$ only, which grows small in comparison to the size of $\Delta G$ as $T$ increases.
To answer your question, the reaction will theoretically tend towards an equal yield of both products.
ps-es
ps. To be honest, as must as I admittedly also seek for these type of generalist answers, each reaction/substitution-elimination competition should be looked at with a fresh perspective, considering electronic/steric effects of the reactants and stabilities of transition states.
pps. to anyone reading, I'm quite an amateur chem student so please correct me if any part of this is incorrect/confusing. thank you!

Equal yield of both products? Did you read the comments? If you have to go on about thermodynamics, which only confused you and OP both, enthalpies of these reactions are different. Better reasoning is that only OH gets deprotonated, because it's much more acidic.

How does deprotonation of OH relate to temperature? I’m supposing that OP is referring to how the favourabilities of both reactions change with respect to temp, then enthalpies are constants which aren’t that impt as temp grows

Then fix your wording, it was like you said that rising temp. would cause amounts for both products to become similar, when it shouldn't really affect this proportion.
